# Why isn't my mail sent?

Tags: forms, emails

I'm writing my first module that will show a form to users, who submit data that is sent as a mail to the people chosen from a list.

But there is an issue; the mail is not sent. What is the problem with my code?

```
function my_module_menu() {

$items['kategori'] = array(

'page callback' => 'my_module_kategori',

'access callback' => TRUE,

'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

);

return $items;

}


function my_module_cmp($a, $b) {

  $a = (array) $a;

  $b = (array) $b;

  return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);

}


function my_module_kategori() {

// Show both the form and the title

return array(

    'form' => drupal_get_form('my_module_form'),

);

}

function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {

// The form

$form['offert'] = array(

    '#title' => t('Skicka offertförfrågan till FLERA leverantörer samtidigt!'),

    '#type' => 'fieldset'

);

$form['offert']['question'] = array(

    '#type' => 'textarea',

    '#title' => t('Förfrågan'),

    '#default_value' =>  t('Skriv en förfrågan till dina utvalda leverantörer här....'),

    '#cols' => 50,

    '#rows' => 5,

    '#resizable' => FALSE

);

$form['offert']['name'] = array(

    '#type' => 'textfield',

    '#title' => t('Namn'),

    '#default_value' => t('Ditt namn....'),

    '#size' => 33,

    '#maxlength' => 64

);

$form['offert']['mail'] = array(

    '#type' => 'textfield',

    '#title' => t('Epost'),

    '#default_value' => t('Epost....'),

    '#size' => 14,

    '#maxlength' => 30

);

$form['offert']['compname'] = array(

    '#type' => 'textfield',

    '#title' => t('Företagsnamn'),

    '#default_value' => t('Företagsnamn....'),

    '#size' => 15,

    '#maxlength' => 64

);

$form['offert']['phone'] = array(

    '#type' => 'textfield',

    '#title' => t('Telefon'),

    '#default_value' => t('Telefon...'),

    '#size' => 14,

    '#maxlength' => 20

);

$form['offert']['comptype'] = array(

    '#type' => 'textfield',

    '#title' => t('Företagstyp'),

    '#default_value' => t('Typ av företag...'),

    '#size' => 15,

    '#maxlength' => 64

);

$form['offert']['submit'] = array(

    '#type' => 'submit',

    '#value' => t('Skicka')

);



// The html

$url = taxonomy_get_term_by_name(arg(1));

foreach($url as $term) {

    $tid = $term->tid;

}

$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);

$name = taxonomy_term_title($term);

$terms = taxonomy_get_tree(3,0,1);

usort($terms, "my_module_cmp");

$counter = 0;

$result = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid);

$options = array();



foreach($result as $nid) {

    $form[$nid] = array(

        '#type' => 'fieldset',

    );

    $node = node_load($nid);

    $options[$nid] = $node->title;

    $phone = db_query("SELECT field_phone_value FROM {field_data_field_phone} WHERE entity_id=$nid")->fetchField();

    $body = db_query("SELECT body_value FROM {field_data_body} WHERE entity_id=$nid")->fetchField(); 



    // company image

    $form[$nid]['logo'] = array (

        '#markup' => '<div class="logo"><a href="/branschguiden/'.$nid.'"><img src="hdfsd01372593e5e.gif"></a></div>',

    );



    // title

    $form[$nid]['title'] = array (

        '#markup' => '<div class="title"><a href="/branschguiden/'.$nid.'">' . $node->title . '</a></div>',

    );



    // body

    $form[$nid]['body'] = array (

        '#markup' => '<div class="body"><a href="/branschguiden/'.$nid.'">' . $body . '</a></div>',

    );



    // phone

    $form[$nid]['phone'] = array (

        '#markup' => '<div class="phone"><img src="/sites/hrtorget/themes/hrtorget/images/phone-icon.png">'.$phone.'</div>',

    );



    // checkbox

    $form[$nid]['companies'] = array (

        '#type' => 'checkboxes',

        '#title' => t('Check it'),

        '#options' => $options,

        '#default_value' => array(),

    );



$counter++;

}

return $form;

}

function my_module_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
// Validate that a company has been checked, at all

$valid_companies = $form_state['values']['companies'];

    if (!$valid_companies) {

    form_set_error('companies', 'Du har inte kryssat i något företag');

    }
}

function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

// Send mail to each of the checked companies with the date from the form

$values = $form_state['values'];

$question = $form_state['values']['question'];

$name = $form_state['values']['name'];

$mail = $form_state['values']['mail'];

$compname = $form_state['values']['compname'];

$comptype = $form_state['values']['comptype'];

$phone = $form_state['values']['phone'];

$to = 'Ann array of all the checked companies email';

$from = 'test$tesfd.com';

$subject = 'Offer';



// Get the checkbox values from the form

//  $nids = array_keys($form_state['values']['company_wrapper']);

$nids = array_filter($form_state['values']['companies']);





// Print all the values from the form

drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($form_state['values'], 1).'</pre>');

//  drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($form_state['values']['company_wrapper'], 1).'</pre>');

drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($form_state['values']['companies'], 1).'</pre>');

//  dpm($form_state['values']['company_wrapper']);



$body = 'Mesage text with a all the stuff from the form';



$message = array(

'body' => $body,

'subject' => $subject,

);



foreach ($nids as $nid) {

    // Get the node from nid

    $node = node_load($nid);

    // Get the author of that node

    $user = user_load(array('uid' => $node->uid));

    drupal_set_message(t('DEBUG nod:'.$nid.', användare: '.$user->name.','.$user->mail.'')); // DEBUG



    // Check if the mail has been sent and show a message based on that

    if (drupal_mail('my_module', 'branschguiden', $user->mail, language_default(), $message, $from, TRUE)) {

        drupal_set_message(t('Mail sent to %name',array('%name' => $user->name)));

    }

    // If no mail was sent.

    else {

        drupal_set_message(t('Error')); 

    }

}

}
```

Comment: As side note, the string passed to `t()` needs to be written in English, or `t()` will not translate the string. If you are not going to use the translation system used by Drupal, then you should not use the `t()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Drupal's example module mail code

```
$module = 'module_name';
$key = 'key';
$language = language_default();
$params = array();
$from = NULL;
$send = FALSE;
$message = drupal_mail($module, $key, $email, $language, $params, $from, $send);

$message['subject'] = $subject;
$message['body'] = array();
$message['body'][] = $line1;
$message['body'][] = $line2;

// Retrieve the responsible implementation for this message.
$system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);

// Format the message body.
$message = $system->format($message);

// Send e-mail.
$message['result'] = $system->mail($message);
```

so `$system->mail($message)` actually sends the mail

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Havent had the time to try it out yet, though. Will to it tomorrow morning.

Comment: So, now I'm using that code and there's still no mail sent. Do I have to set up any settings of some sort?

Comment: Well check if your server can send mail.  Setup a contact form and send an email to yourself.   Tell me if that works or not

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if (drupal_mail('my_module', 'branschguiden', $user->mail, language_default(), $message, $from, TRUE)) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Mail sent to %name',array('%name' => $user->name)));
}
// If no mail was sent.
else {
    drupal_set_message(t('Error')); 
}
```

to

```
 $result = drupal_mail('my_module', 'branschguiden', $user->mail, language_default(), $message, $from, TRUE))
  if ($result['result'] == TRUE) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Mail sent to %name',array('%name' => $user->name)));
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending your message and it was not sent.'), 'error');
  }
```